# A constraint optimization, requiring some components to be zero

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Suppose it has a unique local  maximizer at $x_0$. Now we consider the constraint optimization problem

$$\max_x f(x) \text{ s.t. } x_{k+1} = \cdots = x_n = 0$$

where $x_i$ stands for the $i$-th component of vector $x$. Assume that the negative Hessian of $f$ evaluated at $x_0$ is identity matrix. What would be the solution?

The book claims that the solution is $x_0$ except we set the last $n-k$ components to zero, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Ignoring terms with order higher than 2, I can prove the claim. But I don't know how to deal with higher-order term rigorously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicion is wrong. Consider the following example: Let $f(\theta,\phi)$ denote the height over sea level at the point on earth with geographical coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$. The function $f$ has a unique global maximum at the point  $(\theta_0,\phi_0)$ corresponding to Mount Everest. This does not tell you anything about the elevation at the points $(\theta,0)$ $\bigl(-{\pi\over2}\leq\theta\leq {\pi\over2}\bigr)$ on the Greenwich meridian.

Comment: I need to think about it. Maybe the textbook is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I think I missed assumptions from the book and have re-edited my question.